# htaccess rewrite url with a parameter that equals 0

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to change

```
detail.php?cid=$category&ccid=$category2&cccid=$category3&fid=$id&ftitle=$titleseo
```

to

```
detail/$category/$category2/$category3/$id/$titleseo
```

But in case one of the parameters equals 0, the parameter should not be visible.
So in case `$category=0`, the url should become:

```
detail/$category2/$category3/$id/$titleseo
```

In case `$category2=0`, the url should become:

```
detail/$category/$category3/$id/$titleseo
```

Is this possible with a rewrite rule in htaccess and if yes how should this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this considering `/$category/$category2/$category3/` have given names `/$id/$titleseo` are fixed :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase  /
RewriteRule ^detail/(\$category)?/?(\$category2)?/?(\$category3)?/?(\$id)/(\$titleseo)$  - [E=PASS:cid=$1&ccid=$2&cccid=$3&fid=$4&ftitle=$5]
RewriteCond %{ENV:PASS} (.*)(&)[a-z]+=&(.*)$|[a-z]+=&(.*)$
RewriteRule  ^      details.php?%1%2%3%4 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(&)[a-z]+=&(.*)$|[a-z]+=&(.*)$
RewriteRule  ^      details.php?%1%2%3%4 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:PASS} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule  ^      details.php?%1 [L]
```

In general use this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^detail/([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?(\$id)/(\$titleseo)$  - [E=PASS:cid=$1&ccid=$2&cccid=$3&fid=$4&ftitle=$5]
RewriteCond %{ENV:PASS} (.*)(&)[a-z]+=&(.*)$|[a-z]+=&(.*)$
RewriteRule  ^      details.php?%1%2%3%4 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(&)[a-z]+=&(.*)$|[a-z]+=&(.*)$
RewriteRule  ^      details.php?%1%2%3%4 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:PASS} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule  ^      details.php?%1 [L]
```

The rules above , first make and environment by capturing any request start with details and ended with `/$id/$titleseo` then check that ENV values to see which one has/hasn't a value and finally redirect it accordingly.

Both rules work in case of three levels of categories if you need more you could edit the rules like this :

Add this `([^/]+)?/?` after  `RewriteRule ^detail/` then `[E=PASS:cid=$1&ccid=$2&cccid=$3&ccccid=$4&fid=$5&ftitle=$6]` at the end , you could compare to see the difrenec between this and previous one to get a criteria , and finally add `%5` to  `/details.php?%1%2%3%4 [L]` like this `/details.php?%1%2%3%4%5 [L]` and so on .

Comment: Many thanks Mohammed, somehow this does not work for me.
If I enter 

detail/schlagzeilen/algemein/0/497/kitas-bahnen-muellabfuhr-hier-wird-ab-dienstag-in-der-region-gestreikt

I get error 404.

I have currently the following rule that works:

RewriteRule ^detail/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) detail.php?cid=$1&ccid=$2&cccid=$3&fid=$4&&ftitle=$5

But like said it leaves the categories that are 0 also in, and i would to leave them out. I hope you can help me.

Comment: @SpiekVier put RewriteBase / under RewriteEngine On and test again

Answer (score 0):

Did not get the code from Mohammed to work so far, but used

```
RewriteRule ^detail/?([0-9a-zA-Z]+)?/?([0-9a-zA-Z]+)?/?([0-9a-zA-Z]+)?/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) detail.php?cid=$1&ccid=$2&cccid=$3&fid=$4&&ftitle=$5
```